# Cannot get the correct result following the division algorithm

Tags: algorithms, division-algebras

I have the following algorithm which is supposed to be a Division algorithm:

[image]

where **m** is a's number of digits and **n** is the b's number of digits.

I tried to follow the steps taking **a = 42** , **b = 6** and the base **β = 10**, but I was not able to get the correct result which is 6.

I realy do not know what I am doing wrong.

For example I calculate the first r as follows :
**r = 2 * 10 + 4** 
Is this correct or not ?

Comment: What are you getting? Perhaps $7$?

Comment: No, big numbers for example 640, I think I am not calculating correctly the first "r"

Comment: If you don't show your work, how can we find the error?

Comment: In my work I am calculating the first r like this: 
r = 2 * 10 + 4, is this correct or not ?

Comment: @RossMillikan any idea ?

Comment: No, the whole algorithm is opaque to me.  What are $m,n$?  Are the $a_i$ the digits of $a$? Without commentary, it is impossible

Comment: I edited the question, \[a_{i}\] is the digit in the position i of a